# Why is FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY 16, not 8?

Tags: windows, winapi

Why did Microsoft reserve the value `0x8` (8, bit 3) as a [File Attribute Constant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/gg258117.aspx)?
 `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` [is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/gg258117.aspx#FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) `0x10` (16, bit 4).

Bit 3 is the only reserved bit. For what?

Comment: I keep a copy of the first DDK for Windows NT around.  It documents the flag in a comment inside ntddk.h: "Note:  0x00000008 is reserved for use for the old DOS VOLID (volume ID) and is therefore not considered valid in NT."  Move on, nothing to see there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some very [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147096#comment-83276714) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147096#comment-83278632), I think I know the answer. From [wdm.h](http://www.codemachine.com/downloads/win71/wdm.h) itself:

```
//
// Define the file attributes values
//
// Note:  0x00000008 is reserved for use for the old DOS VOLID (volume ID)
//        and is therefore not considered valid in NT.
//...

#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY             0x00000001  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN               0x00000002  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM               0x00000004  
//OLD DOS VOLID                             0x00000008

#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY            0x00000010  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE              0x00000020  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE               0x00000040  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL               0x00000080  
...
```

The value 8 had been used for the volume ID, so NT chose to avoid it.

Answer (score 5):

Usually a *reserved* value indicates that at some point in the past, perhaps in a released version of Windows that has long since been deprecated, or perhaps in a development version that was never publicly released, that value was used for some purpose, but the value no longer has meaning.

By marking the value as reserved, future developers are prevented from re-using that value. Were that value to be re-used then it could lead to unexpected behaviour in legacy software.

In this case, whilst you say that bit 3 is reserved, I cannot see any evidence of that in the header file. The header file I have has these macro definitions:

```
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY             0x00000001  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN               0x00000002  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM               0x00000004  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY            0x00000010  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE              0x00000020  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE               0x00000040  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL               0x00000080  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY            0x00000100  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE          0x00000200  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT        0x00000400  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED           0x00000800  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE              0x00001000  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED  0x00002000  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED            0x00004000  
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL              0x00010000
```

I don't infer from this that bit 3 is reserved, just that it is not used.

Based on the discussion from the comments, the values of the read only, hidden, system, directory and archive attributes are the same as the analogous values used by DOS and the FAT file system.

For example, the [sample fastfat filesystem](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/aa6e0b36eb932099fa4eb950a6f5e289a23b6d6e/filesys/fastfat/fat.h) driver has these macro declarations:

```
#define FAT_DIRENT_ATTR_READ_ONLY        0x01
#define FAT_DIRENT_ATTR_HIDDEN           0x02
#define FAT_DIRENT_ATTR_SYSTEM           0x04
#define FAT_DIRENT_ATTR_VOLUME_ID        0x08
#define FAT_DIRENT_ATTR_DIRECTORY        0x10
#define FAT_DIRENT_ATTR_ARCHIVE          0x20
#define FAT_DIRENT_ATTR_DEVICE           0x40
```

So we might infer that when the Windows API was created, these same values were carried forward, presumably so that developers who were already familiar with the values did not have to learn a new competing set of values. The value corresponding to bit 3 in DOS/FAT did not have a direct analogue as a Windows file attribute, so it was left unused.

All of this is speculation though, and I suspect that you'd need to find one of the original Windows API developers to confirm this.

Comment: Bit 3 is `FAT_DIRENT_ATTR_VOLUME_ID` (8). On a FAT volume it gets set internally on a file in the root directory to store the volume label.  See [`FatConstructLabelDirent`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/aa6e0b36eb932099fa4eb950a6f5e289a23b6d6e/filesys/fastfat/dirsup.c#L2435) in the sample fastfat filesystem driver. See also discussion of attribute 8 / bit 3 in [DOS Int 21h calls](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm) for finding files (e.g. AH=11h and AH=4Eh) and creating files (e.g. AH=16h and AX=6C00h) to query and set the volume label.

Comment: @eryksun How does that relate to the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_XXX values?

Comment: That's probably the answer @eryksun: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2803.htm! Please change your comment into one so I can accept it.

Comment: OK, I can guess that when the Windows API was being created the values for read only, hidden, system, directory and archive were carried forward from the analagous flags from DOS.  Which is why there is a hole at bit 3 because that value didn't come through to the Windows API. That makes sense. Still, I don't think that `0x00000008` is reserved in any way, it just hasn't been used yet.

Comment: because this is really file [attributes](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/aa6e0b36eb932099fa4eb950a6f5e289a23b6d6e/filesys/fastfat/fat.h#L365), and if look in code - it used exactly as file attributes - [`Buffer->FileAttributes = Fcb->DirentFatFlags`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/aa6e0b36eb932099fa4eb950a6f5e289a23b6d6e/filesys/fastfat/fileinfo.c#L1107)

Comment: @RbMm Only on one specific file system. You need to appreciate the level of abstraction that Win32 puts over the top of the file system implementation. No reason why `0x00000008` could not be used for some new attribute in the future.

Comment: i simply note How does that relate to the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_XXX, however now even fastfat [not allow set](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/aa6e0b36eb932099fa4eb950a6f5e289a23b6d6e/filesys/fastfat/fileinfo.c#L2169) this attribute. may be this worked only under ms-dos, but if i not forget early was way use this for hide folder - was possible set this attribute on folder and it become inaccessible (so hidden with all it files) , but after remove `FAT_DIRENT_ATTR_VOLUME_ID` - again folder become folder

Comment: @RbMm My point is that these attribute values don't map directly to raw file system meta data. They will be mapped by the file system driver. They'll just happen to have these same values due to historical reasons dating back to the lay of the land when the Windows API was being developed. I'm sure that there's no reason why `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_XXX` had to have these values.

Comment: fact that 0x8 ( `FAT_DIRENT_ATTR_VOLUME_ID`) now simply not used. about mapping - if look for example how fastfat set attributes on file - it take it from `FILE_BASIC_INFO` and write as is in `DirentFatFlags` and `Attributes` . and return attributes to user from `DirentFatFlags`. and check this field for different `FAT_DIRENT_ATTR_XXX`. so based on this we can assume that `FAT_DIRENT_ATTR_XXX` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_XXX` is the same in current implementation. however all this also informational, not for use in real code

Comment: @RbMm So the implementation takes advantage of the common values for the FAT file system. But other file systems will no doubt be different.

Comment: agree, but in old ntfs code this attribute also exist - https://github.com/DeDf/ParseNTFS/blob/master/ntfs.h#L1294

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter Can you provide a reference for that please

Comment: @DavidHeffernan see wdm.h in my answer and Hans Passant's comment.

Comment: Thanks for adding that reference. An unattributed statement wasn't very helpful. Odd that the SDK doesn't mark it reserved, but the DDK does.